# Using return vs return 0 for main function in c

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

In my book on C, the author usually formats `main()` like this:

```
main()
{
     /* Some code */
     return;
}
```

But sometimes, he formats `main()` like this:

```
main()
{
     /* Some code */
     return 0;
}
```

What's the difference?  Does it matter?

Comment: If he's declaring `main()` rather than `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, the book probably isn't written to follow best-practices as-is.

Comment: return 0; means program exited successful and atleast in (unix) while return just terminates the program regardles of it's state. in void functions, it it's an exit point

Comment: Tell us what book it is so we can make sure no one buys it, it is teaching non-standard practices.

Comment: I'm using _C By Example_.  It's from somewhere in the 80's, so I wouldn't be surprised if standards have changed.  It doesn't even talk about GUI's or graphics.

Comment: Old versions of `C` permitted declaring `main` like this. Never write it in new code. (A rare exception would be that the C standard permits implementations to specify acceptable alternative declarations of `main`, and an embedded C implementation might do this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C standard says that (draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))

#### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. **It shall be defined with a return type of `int`** and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Now, if a function has return type other than `void` then you have  to use

```
return exp;
```

if its return type is `void` then you can use (not necessary)

```
return;
```

In case of `main` you can use `return 0;` but C99 allow you to omit the return statement.

Comment: That explains a lot.  My book is sort of old, and I guess `main()` didn't have to be type `int` when it was written.

Comment: The compiler like **Turbo C++** (which is very old and obsolete) supports `void main` definition. In older C, if the return type of a function were missing then it implicitly converted to `int`. But C99 and latter drops this feature.

Answer (score 2):

First, `main` should be declared with:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The version with command arguments has some variants, like `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

It must return `int` to conform the standard. And because of that, you must return an `int` at the end, `return 0` if the program runs normally.

Note that in C99 or above, you can omit `return 0`. If `main` is executed to the end, `return 0` is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

The return value indicates (un)successful completion to the environment, allowing said environment to monitor it instead of parsing printed messages. - see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

You should use `return 0` in `main`, with a properly declared `main` function.  In functions declared as `void`, you can just `return` without a value, or let it fall off the end (no `return` statement).